# contract.methods ** is not a function using upgradeable contract and web3

Tags: web3js, proxy-contracts

On the BSC testnet I have created the following Proxy (upgradeable) contract:
[`0xe73585adad24f0994b794eb276561303e1f46a9a`](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xe73585adad24f0994b794eb276561303e1f46a9a) with a related implementation contract: [`0x63d68a352ae2201a8ebb399801ea6f796f50d807`](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x63d68a352ae2201a8ebb399801ea6f796f50d807#code).

I am using web3js to contact the contract using this setup:

```
const proxyAddress = "0xe73585adAd24f0994b794eB276561303E1F46A9a";
const abi = [{
  inputs: [],
  name: "migrate",
  outputs: [{ internalType: "bool", name: "", type: "bool" }],
  stateMutability: "payable",
  type: "function",
}]

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, proxyAddress);

const contract = contract ;
const sender = localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY);
contract.methods
  .migrate()
   .send({
    from: sender,
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("Success", res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

The abi is taken from the implementation contract - so I am using the proxy contract to envoke the web3.eth.Contract method and the abi from the implementation contract.

I get the following error:

[image]

I have tried to use `contract.methods.implementation().migrate()` and `contract.functions.implementation().migrate()`. But without any luck

I am currently using [`web3 v. 1.7.3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3).

I might be misunderstanding something but I am quite sure that you need to use the proxy contract address but the abi from the implementation contract?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a double array when setting the ABI.
I had the reference to the ABI bee wrapped around a second array like this:

```
[
  [{
    inputs: [],
    name: "migrate",
    outputs: [{ internalType: "bool", name: "", type: "bool" }],
    stateMutability: "payable",
    type: "function",
  }]
]
```

Changing it to this fixed the issue:

```
[{
  inputs: [],
  name: "migrate",
  outputs: [{ internalType: "bool", name: "", type: "bool" }],
  stateMutability: "payable",
  type: "function",     
}]
```